# Cannot Send Messages to remote MSMQ

Tags: c#, msmq

**My DEV server** is Windows 2008 R2 has MSMQ installed. **My local development machine** is Windows XP, also has MSMQ installed. Obviously they are 2 different MSMQ versions.

In my code I have something like

```
        MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(@"formatname:DIRECT=OS:MyDevServer\Private$\MyQueue", QueueAccessMode.Send);
        Message message = new Message(value, new BinaryMessageFormatter());
        queue.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
        queue.Close();
        return message.Id;
```

to send messages. My intention is to make the messages appear in my DEV server's private queue.

I have this queue created on DEV server, with permissions of

- Everyone - Get Permissions, Send Message
- My domain account to create the queue - I can do everything
- MyDevServer$ - Get Properties, Get Permissions, Send Message
- Anonymous Logon - Send Message

I can run the code locally without exception, and I can also obtain the message Id. On my local Windows XP's MSMQ I can see I have `Outgoing Queue` -> `DIRECT=OS:MyDevServer\Private$\MyQueue` -> `Queue Messages`. The new message appears in this queue. After a while the message is gone. BUT I cannot see it anywhere in my DEV server's queue.

**UPDATE:** I found SO post "[MSMQ on Win2008 R2 won’t receive messages from older clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371905/msmq-on-win2008-r2-won-t-receive-messages-from-older-clients)" which solved my problem, the code above is correct, but the target host was blocking traffic.

Comment: I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371905/msmq-on-win2008-r2-wont-receive-messages-from-older-clients and enabled UDP port 3527 to solve the problem.

Comment: typically posters are encouraged to post their solution as an answer and self-accept. it may seem self aggrandizing, however, it ensures the question properly indexes as being answered.